# c# winforms Instantiate of dynamically created Pictureboxes doesn't works

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to instantiate two pictureboxes created at runtime. I've assigned those to a panel, and I try to instantiate this in the form load event.
Here is my Class with the two pictureboxes and the panel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

namespace AudioNodeGUI.Klassen
{
    public class DateiÖffnenUndAuswählenSteuerelement : Form
    {
        public int xLoc = 0;
        public int yLoc = 0;
        public Point loc1;
        public Point loc2;
        public Panel elementpanel;

        public DateiÖffnenUndAuswählenSteuerelement()
        {
            this.loc1 = new Point(xLoc, yLoc);
            this.loc2 = new Point(xLoc + 41, yLoc);
            this.elementpanel = new Panel
            {
                Name = "elementpanel",
                Size = new Size(154, 22),
                Location = new Point(xLoc, yLoc),
            };
        }

        public Panel Zeichnen()
        {
            PictureBox browseImage = new PictureBox()
            {
                Name = "browseimage",
                Size = new Size(41, 22),
                Location = loc1,
                Image = Image.FromFile(@"F:\AudioNodeGUI\images\Browse_used_files.jpg"),
                Visible = true,
            };
            PictureBox fileImage = new PictureBox()
            {
                Name = "fileimage",
                Size = new Size(113, 22),
                Location = loc2,
                Image = Image.FromFile(@"F:\AudioNodeGUI\images\Filebutton1.jpg"),
                Visible = true,
            };
            browseImage.Click += new EventHandler(browseImage_Clicked);
            fileImage.Click += new EventHandler(fileImage_Clicked);
            this.elementpanel.Controls.Add(browseImage);
            this.elementpanel.Controls.Add(fileImage);
            return elementpanel;
        }

        public void browseImage_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void fileImage_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
        open.Filter = "Audio Files(*.wav; *.mp3; *.aif; *.aiff)";
        }
    }
}
```

And in the form load event, I've tried to instantiate the custom control:

```
private void AudioNodeWindow_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AudioNodeGUI.Klassen.DateiÖffnenUndAuswählenSteuerelement element = new AudioNodeGUI.Klassen.DateiÖffnenUndAuswählenSteuerelement();
        Panel panel = element.Zeichnen();
        this.Controls.Add(panel);

    }
```

But when I ran the programm, the control wasn't shown. Do you know where i have a mistake?

Comment: I think you should create a new panel in `Zeichnen`, because you can't add a control to two forms.

Comment: is your panel visible?

Comment: Oh, sorry, my mistake, there was a ToolStripMenu which blocked the pictureboxes, ups...